# -[UILabel _startMarquee] crash on iOS 12.2 iPhone XS Max

Tags: swift, uilabel, ios12, iphone-xs-max

I don't have any ideas about the crush. I see the crush log on Fabric. And NO Repetition.

1.View all the code that use the CAGradientLayer
2.Multiple attempts to enter the foreground from the background

```
self.airHubbleView?.dismissAirHubble(isHaveNext: false, completion: { [weak self] (isComplate) in
            guard let `self` = self else { return }
            self.airHubbleView?.removeFromSuperview()
            self.airHubbleView = nil
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
        })
```

airHubbleView is a custom View. The Custom view uses the CAGradientLayer to create a color gradient.
Stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
-[CAGradientLayer _clearContents]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x280126a00
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1b789f758 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1b6aa7d00 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1b77b86ac -[NSOrderedSet initWithSet:copyItems:]
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1b78a50fc ___forwarding___
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1b78a6eb0 _CF_forwarding_prep_0
5  UIKitCore                      0x1e4b964f0 -[UILabel _startMarquee]
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b72b0374 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b72b18f4 _dispatch_client_callout
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b72bd794 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
9  CoreFoundation                 0x1b782f534 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
10 CoreFoundation                 0x1b782a1e4 __CFRunLoopRun
11 CoreFoundation                 0x1b7829764 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
12 GraphicsServices               0x1b9a65dd4 GSEventRunModal
13 UIKitCore                      0x1e478000c UIApplicationMain
14 iReader                        0x104435b08 main (main.m:23)
15 libdyld.dylib                  0x1b72e8ffc start
```

I want to get some ideas.